# Function not implemented error when using PiCamera in python ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, camera

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry pi 4 . I used a raspberry pi camera . But PiCamera() module dont work although i installed it with pip and `raspistill -o image.jpeg` works just fine so the camera is setup sucessfully. this is the error

```
 python3 -c "from picamera import PiCamera; PiCamera()"
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.camera_info'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 367, in __init__
    with mo.MMALCameraInfo() as camera_info:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2346, in __init__
    super(MMALCameraInfo, self).__init__()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 631, in __init__
    mmal_check(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.camera_info': Function not implemented
```

Comment: Check the cabling, thoroughly, making sure you didn't break it.

Comment: not cabling problem . the command raspistill -o is working fine in terminal and can capture image

Comment: Ah... `b'vc.camera_info'` - the `b` in the beginning might be an indication that the thing you installed with pip isn't compatible with Python3 - as indicated by `python3...` appearing above it. Note `python` (version 2) is not available in Ubuntu 20.04.'

Comment: Whether it is possible to `apt install python` to get a working python2.x is unknown to me. Py 2 isn't present in 18.04.5 either. It was present in 16.04.